# If and else issue with python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently learning Python to do some **webscraping** and I'm facing with an issue with If and Else

The current code is the following :

```
r= requests.get(urlpage, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'online'})

result = print(div.string)

if result == 'Online':
    print('Ok')
else:
    print('Next Time')
```

I have written `print(div.string)` to get rid of div elements which is : `<div class="online">Online</div>` so I get "Online" only which is working

but when I try `if` and `else` I always get as result "Next Time" while I'm supposed to get "Ok".

At this point i'm kinda lost, do you have any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: `print()` as a function returns `None`, You probably want `result = div.string`

Comment: absolutely :) thank you

Answer (score 1):

just get string directly, no need for print

also use lower function, makes it easier to compare

```py
r= requests.get(urlpage, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'online'})

result = div.string # just get string directly, no need for print

if lower(result) == 'online':
    print('Ok')
else:
    print('Next Time')
```

Comment: It's working thank you very much :)